# Beginner Powershell: Select and Store SID

Tags: powershell

I'm brand new to Powershell (literally 2 hours), all I want to do is get my SID and store it as a variable to use later in the script.

As far as I'm aware, the easiest way to get your SID is to use the command

> whoami /user

which displays the current user and it's associated SID.

How would I go about selecting the SID and storing it?

> $variable = whoami /user | ....

Answer (score 0):

You can do, $mySid = Get-ADUser  -Identity *username* | select SID

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to ad module (and the user is AD user) then you can use m0lochwalker's answer.

The below will snippet will work for both AD and local user snippet :

```
 $mysid = gwmi win32_useraccount -Filter "name='$($env:USERNAME)'" | select -ExpandProperty sid
$mysid
```